# How to get logged User_Id in Spring MVC

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the logged username and id in spring MVC.
I can get the logged username easily but I am unable to get the user_id.
I am using this piece of code to get the user/principal detail.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

If someone know how to get the logged user_id?

Comment: Is it your internal id?

Comment: @ bart.s It is saved user id. But when user login then I want to get its id similarly as I can get its name.

Comment: Spring security will generate a instance of "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails" which contains username. If you want to have access to your User schema, you will need to implement your own subclass of UserDetails and pupulate it righ after you login. Please provide further details on how you are implementing login to provide a better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`
in your `User` class see below example.

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails,Serializable{
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      @Column(name = "userId")
      private long userId;
}
```

And then use following code for getting user details.

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```